# Run MVC controller action without the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ExcelResult action result that returns Microsoft Excel documents, based off the [Stephen Walther tip](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/16/asp-net-mvc-tip-2-create-a-custom-action-result-that-returns-microsoft-excel-documents.aspx).  Basically it just writes a stream out to the Response.  When debugging VS 2010 (ASP.NET Dev Server), it runs fine, but when I run it on an IIS 6 box, I get the following error:

> The view 'GenerateExcel' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Home/GenerateExcel.aspx
>   ~/Views/Home/GenerateExcel.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/GenerateExcel.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/GenerateExcel.ascx

There is no associated View, and therefore no file, but there shouldn't have to be.  What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

By simply returning void instead of an ActionResult, I no longer have this issue.  Instead of returning the ExcelResult, I'm explicitly calling it's ExecuteResult method, which is writing to the output stream.

**Before**

```
public ActionResult GenerateExcel()
{
    return this.Excel(parameters);
}
```

**After**

```
    public void GenerateExcel()
{
ExcelResult excelResult = this.Excel(parameters);
excelResult.ExecuteResult(null);
}
```

After that, I had security issues with my NTLM authentication, but they 'went away' (meaning I expect them to come back).  For now, though, everything is working properly.

Comment: Don't you feel that it is a bit difficult to say what you are doing wrong without showing what you are doing (some code or something)? Unfortunately I don't have telepathic skills.

Comment: Well you can basically view the code on the link.  It's returning an ActionResult that's really an ExcelResult whose ExecuteResult method is writing to the output stream.

Comment: @DougJones Old question, but just wanted to point out: it's better to write questions in a format so that people don't have to follow links to understand the basic parts of the question. The question ought to be clear enough to be understood without links; links can be added to provide additional, in-depth resources etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure your action method does not return a ActionResult:

```
public void DoSomething()
```

Comment: Oh, no each action should return an ActionResult. In this case he wants an `ExcelResult` which is a custom action result but still an action result.

Comment: Every public method in a controller is an action method and can be called by suitable URL. While he is writing a stream into Response it can work.

Comment: That got me to a different error!  I just saw a blank page instead of the attached excel doc.  I saw in Fiddler I'm now getting a 401 access denied error over the NTLM windows authentication, though the other controller actions (with views) display just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the code for the action result in much detail, but there must be something wrong with your action result.  Did you inherit from some other action result as opposed to the ActionResult class?  Did you call base.ExecuteResult?  If so, that would explain why it is looking for the view.  I have created several custom controller actions to return various file types and they never look for a view.

I agree with the comments on the answer saying to return void.  That definitely is a hack.  You should not call ExecuteResult from inside your action.  You are basically writing directly to the response stream from your controller action.  Obviously it works but it really doesn't fit the MVC model.